# TikZ: Recalculate a variable in a for-loop using bitset

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I'm trying to draw the graph of a function, which I'm interested in, and for this I need to recalculate the value of a variable in a for-loop. Following the suggestion from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392403), I use the for-loop which comes with the math library. For my computations I also need the binary expansion of the counter of the loop and for this I use the bitset package. However, I cannot make it work and I do not get what's wrong. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}
\usepackage{bitset}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1, ..., 10}{%
    \bitsetSetDec{mybitset}{\i};

    \tikzmath{
        \x = 0; 
        \y = 0;

        for \j in {0,...,3}{
             \b = \bitsetGet{mybitset}{\j};
             \x = \x + \b;
             \y = \y +2* \b;
       };
    };
    \draw[red,thick] (\x, \y) -- ({\x +0.25}, \y);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It seems to me that the problem is in this line:

```
\b = \bitsetGet{mybitset}{\j};
```

but I don't see how to fix it. Any suggestions? Thanks already in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! There are basically two issues:

1. You cannot just expect to be able to assign the value of a macro like this.
2. It seems that you cannot go with `\j` larger than `\i`.

To solve the first problem, you can declare a function that returns the value. This function is called `bitsetGet` and it expects the first argument to be a string delimited by `"..."`. Restricting the loop variable such that the second problem does not arise one gets

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{bitset}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{bitsetGet}{2}{\begingroup
\edef\temp{\noexpand\edef\noexpand\pgfmathresult{\bitsetGet{#1}{#2}}}%
\temp
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {4, ..., 10}{%
    \bitsetSetDec{mybitset}{\i};
    \tikzmath{
        \x = 0; 
        \y = 0;     
         for \j in {0,1,2,3}{
               \b = bitsetGet("mybitset",\j); 
              \x = \x + \b;
              \y = \y +2* \b;
        };
        %print {$x=\x, y=\y$};
    };
    %\typeout{\x,\y}
    \draw[red,thick] (\x, \y) -- ({\x +0.25}, \y);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am assuming here that this is a `tikzmath` question. Obviously there are much simpler ways to get this output. However, I started to realize only recently how powerful `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` can be. (Here its powers are not used. It is really convenient when drawing some stuff and parsing the coordinates with new tricks.)

Comment: Isn't `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{bitsetGet}{2}{\edef\pgfmathresult{\bitsetGet{#1}{#2}}}` easier?

Comment: @egreg Yes, it is, thanks! I would still prefer to keep the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` to be prepared for using this when the user also wants to use the `fpu` library. One can then locally switch on a non-fpu number format.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!